# await AsyncMethod() versus await await Task.Factory.StartNew<TResult>(AsyncMethod)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, async-await

Given the following method:

```
public async Task<MyObject> DoSomethingAsync() {
    // do some work
    await OpenSomeFileAsync();
    return new MyObject();
}
```

Is there a difference between:

```
public async void SomeEventHandler(EventArgs args) {
    var myObject = await await Task.Factory.StartNew<Task<MyObject>>( DoSomethingAsync);
    // do something with myObject
}
```

and:

```
public async void SomeEventHandler(EventArgs args) {
    var myObject = await DoSomethingAsync();
    // do something with myObject
}
```

I was thinking that the "do some work" part of DoSomethingAsync would happen immediately in a new task in the first case, but to be honest I don't really understand fully how Tasks, async and await are working, and I'm pretty sure I'm just overcomplicating things for myself.

EDIT:

This question came about from looking at this Metro example:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Target-App-e2689782

Specifically in MainPage.xaml.cs, they have this:

```
var unused = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { // some work... });
// unused is of type Task<TResult>
```

I was trying to rework it without using an anonymous async function and I started wondering, why not just write an async method and await it, instead of calling StartNew and handing in an async function?

Comment: Why would you want to write it out that way? The whole point of using the new `async`/`await` keywords was so that you didn't have to.

Comment: Seems like a bad example piece of code off-hand

Comment: I just took a look myself, and... Wow. Yeah, that "Official Windows SDK Sample" code is **really bad**! I think they've managed to completely miss the point of `async`!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most of the time, adding another `Task` is not useful, but in some cases, it can be.

The difference is if you're on the UI thread (or something similar) and execute `DoSomethingAsync()` directly, its first part (`// do some work`) will also execute on the UI thread, and so will any continuation parts of the method (unless they use `ConfigureAwait()`). On the other hand, if you start another `Task`, both the first part and any following parts of `DoSomethingAsync()` will execute on the `ThreadPool`.

If `DoSomethingAsync()` is written correctly, adding another `Task` shouldn't give you any advantages (and will give you the disadvantage of more overhead), but I can imagine there are cases where it will make a difference.

Also, instead of using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` and two `await`s, you could write:

```
await Task.Run(DoSomethingAsync);
```

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about the part before the await... +1

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a difference: in the first form, you have an extra level of Task, which brings absolutely nothing useful.

The first form is basically equivalent to this:

```
Task<Task<MyObject>> task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<Task<MyObject>>( DoSomethingAsync);
Task<MyObject>> task2 = await task1;
var myObject = await task2;
```

So it doesn't really make sense: you're creating a task that just... creates another task.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I was thinking as much.  If you have a moment could you address my edit?  I'm sort of confused by the approach taken in the example I was looking at...

Comment: @justin, I agree with James, it's a really bad example... there's no reason to create a task on an async method, since it already returns a task

Comment: There *is* a difference between the two (and I don't mean just overhead), see my answer.